# there is no response from the web service

Tags: ios, web-services, soap

I have a web service in IOS which I give the ip address and it will return the country. The code is:

for .m:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @implementation ViewController

 @synthesize ipAddress;
 @synthesize activityIndicator;

 - (IBAction)btnFindCountry:(id)sender {
NSString *soapMsg =
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="
 "\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
 "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
 "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
 "<soap:Body>"
 "<FindCountryAsXml xmlns=\"http://www.ecubicle.net/webservices/\">"
 "<V4IPAddress>%@</V4IPAddress>"
 "</FindCountryAsXml>"
 "</soap:Body>"
 "</soap:Envelope>", ipAddress.text];

//---print it to the Debugger Console for verification---
NSLog(@"%@",soapMsg);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://www.ecubicle.net/iptocountry.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//---set the various headers---
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                       [soapMsg length]];
[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://www.ecubicle.net/webservices/FindCountryAsXml"
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];



[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//---set the HTTP method and body---
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//---start animating —
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                       delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
 }

 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
[webData setLength: 0];
 }

 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
[webData appendData:data];
 }

 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
   didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
[webData release];
[connection release];
 }

 -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes]
                    length:[webData length]
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//---shows the XML---
NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
[theXML release];

//---stop animating---
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];

[connection release];
[webData release];
 }

 - (void)dealloc {
[ipAddress release];
[activityIndicator release];
[super dealloc];
 }
 @end
```

and .h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITextField *ipAddress;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

NSMutableData *webData;
NSMutableString *soapResults;
NSURLConnection *conn;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *ipAddress;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

 -(IBAction) btnFindCountry:(id)sender;

 @end
```

when I run it and enter 3.4.5.6 the result in the debugger is:

```
 WebService[3525:60b] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelop 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><FindCountryAsXml 
 xmlns="http://www.ecubicle.net/webservices/"><V4IPAddress>3.4.5.6</V4IPAddress>
 </FindCountryAsXml></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

which means that the request is sent successfully and there is no response from the web service

i followed a tutorial which is here http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9780470918029/web-services/consuming_a_web_service_in_your_iphone_a

and the response I supposed to get is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <soap:Body>
        <FindCountryAsXmlResponse
           xmlns="http://www.ecubicle.net/webservices/">
           <FindCountryAsXmlResult>
              <IPCountryService xmlns="">
                 <Country>United States</Country>
              </IPCountryService>
           </FindCountryAsXmlResult>
        </FindCountryAsXmlResponse>
     </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

What's the problem? 
Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried checking with breakpoints, whether your connection is set up

Comment: @rishi there is no breakpoints

Comment: Can you put following log statement in didFailWithError - NSLog(@"Connection fails"); So that you can actually know what is the cause of issue

Comment: @rishi there is no error and it run perfectly but we did not receive response

Comment: Also you have to know how to use breakpoints, then only you can debug issues. You can go through following tutorial - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Comment: What does it prints in this statement - NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

Comment: we followed this tutorial http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9780470918029/web-services/consuming_a_web_service_in_your_iphone_a

Comment: but you have to at least debug on your own.